# PHP function as batch?

Tags: php, batch-file

We're currently working with a free warehouse management system. This exports our store data to the external price search engine all 6 hours. We need to do this hourly due new law changes.

Here comes the riddle: You need to click on a button on the webinterface of our management system to start the export. This calls "host/**admin/exportformate.php?action=export&kExportformat=30&token=1800b8e38ded2ead0f060c18fdbcbfdb**". We solved the problem with losing the session with a firefox addon which reloads the index.php ever 30 secs.

Now when I open up a new window or tab with the URL above, everything runs fine. When I try to open the URL with a **batch** file to set up a cron job for the hourly export, the opened window/tab only refers to "**/admin/exportformate.php?action=export**", drops the rest of the line and doesn't call the action at all.

Is there a way to call this exact php action hourly, ideally with credentials? (No, .htaccess doesn't work with our management system...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your problem seem to be the `&` characters (which has a special meaning in `cmd`). Try to escape them with a caret: `.....action=export^%kExportformat=30^&token=.....`

Comment: Oh great, this actually helped on translating the correct url through the batch to the browser thanks! Sadly this still doesn't trigger the referred php action...

Comment: Addition: Used the caret correctly now, it works thanks! <3